# Birth year using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to calculate  the "birth year" using todays date, say age column has  values of 22,55,30  in the order youngest to oldest using oracle sql .

Comment: Why are there multiple values in one column? Are those multiple rows or one row that is comma delimited?

Comment: those are multiple rows

Comment: Say I'm 10. How do you know if I was born in Jan 2003 - 17 Oct 2003, or 18 Oct 2002 - 31 Dec 2002?

Comment: The age is of now . I mean today is the birthday .

Answer (score 4):

I would store the birthday and calculate age when you need to display that information.

Birthday won't change. Age will change every year.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the age of people whose birthday is today, then you can get the Birth year this way:`

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from SYSDATE) - age as BirthYear
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY BirthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is age, you can't determine birth year exactly. Consider someone born on 31 December 1970. They are

- Less than 1 year of age during the period 31 Dec 1970 — 30 Dec 1971
- 1 year of age during the period 31 Dec 1971 — 30 December 1972
- etc.

And consider someone born the very next week, say 5 January 1971). They are

- Less than 1 year of age during the period 5 Jan 1971 — 4 Jan 1972
- 1 year of age during the period 5 Jan 1972 —4 Jan 1973
- etc.

It is now 2013 (today, in fact, 17 Oct 2013). And all you know about these two individuals is that they are 43 years of age. 2013-43 says 1970 is the birth year, but it's wrong for one of them. Given a date and an age as of that date, the best you can do is get within 1 year of the actual birth year.

You need a date of birth.